# Workaround for clang-3.7 missing Asan bug

Tags: package-management, clang

There is a [known bug](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=22757), to do with the fact that the Debian libclang packages appear to be compiled with autotools, but only the cmake build of the library produces the library for the sanitizers.

The bug effects libclang-common-3.7. It results in link errors such as

```
/usr/bin/ld.gold: error: cannot open /usr/lib/llvm-3.7/bin/../lib/clang/3.7.0/lib/linux/libclang_rt.asan-x86_64.a: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld.gold: error: cannot open /usr/lib/llvm-3.7/bin/../lib/clang/3.7.0/lib/linux/libclang_rt.asan_cxx-x86_64.a: No such file or directory
error: undefined reference to '__asan_option_detect_stack_use_after_return'
error: undefined reference to '__asan_stack_malloc_5'
error: undefined reference to '__asan_report_load4'
error: undefined reference to '__asan_report_load8'
error: undefined reference to '__asan_report_load8'
error: undefined reference to '__asan_handle_no_return'
error: undefined reference to '__asan_report_store_n'
...
```

I just want to know how people are working around it.

To me, this is a huge deal. I'm surprised this bug has gone unfixed for months and there doesn't seem to be a lot of noise about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My workaround is to use the Clang 3.6 packages. If you really require 3.7, you need to build it from source.

The good news is that it is has been recognized as a high priority bug (see [bug 22757](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=22757)).

Comment: Thanks. I worked to get the bug upgraded to high-priority. Clang-3.6 is what I've been using as a workaround, so I think it's quite appropriate if I accept your solution. I don't think anything better will come along before it's fixed properly.

Answer (score 2):

I'm also surprised by how long this bug has been around.   I think it's actually fixed at this point, but there doesn't seem to be any plan to update the older packages.  Luckily, it turns out that fixing the broken packages after installation is quite easy.   You just need to download the correct libraries, and put them in the correct directory.

First, go to http://llvm.org/releases/download.html and find the matching version. I'm running 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04, so to patch clang-3.8 I want "Clang for x86_64 Ubuntu 14.04".  Download directly, or copy the right-click and "Copy Link Address" and use wget:

`wget http://llvm.org/releases/3.8.0/clang+llvm-3.8.0-x86_64-linux-gnu-ubuntu-14.04.tar.xz`

Uncompress:

`tar -xf clang+llvm-3.8.0-x86_64-linux-gnu-ubuntu-14.04.tar.xz`

Then copy the library files (using -n to avoid overwriting existing files):

`sudo cp -n clang+llvm-3.8.0-x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/clang/3.8.0/lib/linux/*.a /usr/lib/llvm-3.8/lib/clang/3.8.0/lib/linux/`

If desired, repeat for any older versions of clang you have installed, although note that if you are using a Linux kernel more recent than 4.1 with a clang version earlier than 3.8 you may encounter another bug with -fsanitize=memory: https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=24155

Comment: Thanks. I'll give this a shot.  Do you happen to know if the packages at llvm.org/apt are up-to-date? I wouldn't mind uninstalling Ubuntu's and going with those.

Comment: At least for 'trusty' through 3.8 as of March 2016, I don't believe that helps you .  The fix was made in February 2016 (https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=22757) but the packages have not been updated since January 2016 (http://llvm.org/apt/trusty/dists/).